# Finding numbered functions within C++ code?

Tags: c++, regex, search

just need your experts advice.

I've hundreds of *.cpp sorce code files which inclue various mumber of test functions, syntax is like:

```
void test1()
...
void test25()
```

A cpp-file may have only one test, void test1(), it may have plenty of test, for example void test266() or whatever number.

I like to count all these functions, respectively I want to find the test function with the max. number in
function name.
This probably is the last one but it need not be the last one, e.g.

```
void test1()
[
...
}
void test3()
[
...
}
void test2()
[
...
}
```

will may also happen.

Any idea how to assembe this information quick?
I'm somewhat familiar with C++ (VC 2013) but not so much with (C++) regex which I may have to use.

Without regex: Reading cpp file line by line and searching the pattern testnumber , counting them and then executing this program
via batch for all *.cpp files in a folder I will manage but is there a tool which will do the job easier?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: [grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) and [sort](https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)? Something like `grep -r . -e "void test" | sort`

Comment: `perl -nE 'BEGIN { $n = 0 } if (/\btest(\d+)\b/ && $1 > $n) { $n = $1 } END { say $n }'`?

Comment: Or alternatively, since you are a Windows user, I would recommend notepad++ . It has some easy 'find in files', you should be able to enter the pattern for "void test*()"

Comment: Isn't that what a suitable unit testing framework and test runner should manage?

Comment: @ThomasSablik: That will print `test42` _after_ `test1792`, won't it?

Comment: @TonyK `sort -n` is numerical sort

Comment: @ThomasSablik: So the version in your comment won't work then? (And does it even work with `-n`, given that the strings don't start with a number?)

Comment: @TonyK It was an idea how you can solve it. It was a comment. It wasn't a final answer. I'm pretty sure that you can use these both tools to find the last test.

Comment: @ThomasSablik: No, I can't. Can you? If not, your comment was worthless.

Comment: @TonyK Read the man page: `grep -ho -r . -e "test[0-9]*" | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1`

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Obvious once you see it :-)

Comment: Why do you consistently start your function with `[` instead of `{`?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do this in something like python or bash, but it can be done in C++ too, using the `regex` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
    //set up regex
    std::regex reg("void [a-zA-Z]*(\\w*)");
    std::smatch matches;
    //set up file
    std::ifstream infile("path/to/Cpp/file");
    //do the actual stuff
    std::string line;
    int max = 0;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        if (std::regex_search(line, matches, reg))
        {
            int match = std::stoi(matches[1].str());
            if (match >= max)
                max = match;
        }
    }
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, it leads me to the right way!